# Expo run:ios crashes on physical device, works everywhere else

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a react native app that runs normally on simulators, builds fine and runs via testflight as expected. Whenever I try to run the app on my physical device (iPhone se2) one of two things happen.

- (most frequent) app builds with no errors and hangs (as normal), but the app on my phone crashes when the splash screen comes up (again, no logs or errors)
- expo builds but then exits and disconnects

I've tried

- restarting everything
- removing and reinstalling pod files

The only dependencies I've added since running it on my device last are a UI library (native base) and react-native-safari-view. I also only have 5gb of space left on my device (not sure if relevant)

Does anybody know how I can debug this better or what might be wrong?